# If $A$ is symmetry, then different eigenvector correspond to different eigenvalue is orthogonal. But does the converse statement true?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Here is one of my notes proving the statement from $p \rightarrow q$, I am wondering does it correct from $q \rightarrow p$? There is, if different eigenvector correspond to different eigenvalue is orthogonal, then $A$ is symmetry.

[image: proof]

Comment: Consider $A=\text{Col}(e_1,e_1+e_2,2e_3)\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Converse is not necessarily true.

Choose, $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1&0 \\0 & 1&1\\ 1& 0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$

Now, your task is to verify that eigenvctors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of are orthogonal but clearly $A$ is not symmetric.

NOTE: You can expand your theorem to normal matrix $[AA^T =A^TA]$ and every symmetric matrix$[A^T=A]$ is a normal matrix.

But, a normal matrix need not be symmetric and those matrix provide counterexaples of the converse of your mentioned theorem and one such example is mentioned above. Hurry, you can now produce a lot many of them.

Hope it helps. Thanks.